# Bootstrap multiselect drop down list is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a multi selectable list which looks something like this

[image: like that]

This is my HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="months">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#months').multiselect();
});
```

The view I get from the code seems to be fine:

[image]

However, when I click on it, the drop down list won't come out! What could be the reason? I am using the following plugin [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/)

Comment: Is there any error return in the console ?

Comment: Have you included all the required files in the html ?

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: ...or create a fiddle.

Comment: @Mr.Developer - no. Vignesh Raja - yes. Sanjit Bhardwaj - no, because there would be too much code. It's a large application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's so easy to make it work.
You just have to include jQuery and then Bootsrap as the following simple example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#months').multiselect();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple" id="months">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I had all the tags but they were somehow not right. I commented mine out and added yours and it worked. Thanks. Maybe the files were outdated.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! the problem in my code lies in the order of the cdn links placement