# Why is Bootstrap Multiselect not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get Bootstrap Multiselect running but it just doesn't want to function. I already tried everything and just cannot find the issue.
My index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Minimal Bootstrap Multiselect Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-multiselect@0.9.13/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
</head>
<body>

    <select id="minimal-multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="onions">Onions</option>
    </select>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-multiselect@0.9.13/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#minimal-multiselect').multiselect();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This actually loads the multiselect correctly and the css is also working on it. But when i click on it the dropdown just doesn't open. There is also no errors in the console.

I expected the dropdown to open

Comment: Version incompatibility?  Note that the versions of jquery/bootstrap/multiselect used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522194/bootstrap-multiselect-drop-down-list-is-not-showing/48522444#48522444) seem to work ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an issue with bootstrap version, downgrade to lower version

I have updated with a lower version V3.4.1 seems working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Minimal Bootstrap Multiselect Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-multiselect@0.9.13/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
</head>
<body>

    <select id="minimal-multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="onions">Onions</option>
    </select>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-multiselect@0.9.13/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#minimal-multiselect').multiselect();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```